# Unable to force file download from an asp.net page without getting security bar along top of IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

How can I force the Save As Dialog box to show within an asp.net page without getting the browser bar at the top saying "To help protect security IE blocked this site from downloading files..... Click here for options"

It then forces the user to click the Download File option - but this first time they do this nothing happens.

What I need to happen is that the File Download box should be displayed with the options of saving or opening etc.. the file to download.

The asp.net/C# code I am currently using is:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilename");
Response.WriteFile(myfilename);
Response.End();
```

Any ideas why I shouldn't just get the File Download box ?

Comment: there is probably no way if IE is configured or behaving like that on the clients. A web application can do little or nothing in forcing/changing browser bahaviour. How does it work with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Haven't really tested with those yet but I have seen it working in IE on some sites where you don't get any browser warnings - just the Open, Save, Close dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Content Type to "Application/Force-Download" instead

**ASP.NET C# Example:**

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download;");
```

**Fully functional code:**

```
try
        {
            string FileName = Request.QueryString["file"];
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download;");    
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
            Response.WriteFile(@Server.MapPath("download/") + "\\" + FileName);
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Handle Error
        }
```